# Проблема с старым шаблоном HTML

Tags: html

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<HTML>
<HEAD>
  <TITLE>Относительное позиционирование</TITLE>
  <SCRIPT>flag=0;</SCRIPT>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
  <DIV id=kuku style="BORDER:1px solid; WIDTH:200px; 
                      POSITION: relative; TOP:0px; LEFT:50px;">
    <A href=javascript:
    if(flag==0)
    {
      window.document.all.kuku.style.pixelLeft=-50; flag=1;
    }  
    else
    {
      window.document.all.kuku.style.pixelLeft=50; flag=0;
    }
    void(0);">
    Сдвинуть слой
    </A>
  </DIV>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

У меня проблема, не могу разобраться как решить ее.

Comment: Капс бы выключили и выкинули бы свой доктайп, а вобоще почитайте про `html5` и `css3` и не надо в ссылки тулить столько кода - опишите код в функции. а функцию напишите в ссылку. И к тому-же, у вас аттрибут href="" уже закрылся, а следующее : после " - это уже ошибка.

Comment: Самая главная проблема — код устарел лет на пятнадцать :)

Comment: @andreymal ну вот такой код в методичке с лабами дает универ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Целый комплекс проблем. Среди прочего - кавычки не забывайте!

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<HTML>
<HEAD>
  <TITLE>Относительное позиционирование</TITLE>
  <SCRIPT>flag=0;</SCRIPT>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
  <DIV id="kuku" style="BORDER:1px solid; WIDTH:200px; 
                      POSITION: relative; TOP:0px; LEFT:50px;">
    <A href="javascript:
    if(flag==0)
    {
      window.document.all.kuku.style.left=-50; flag=1;
    }  
    else
    {
      window.document.all.kuku.style.left=50; flag=0;
    }
    void(0);">
    Сдвинуть слой
    </A>
  </DIV>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Answer (score 0):

У вас весьма устаревший стартовый шаблон. Вот пример с комментариями (очень общи:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> <!-- Тут вы говорите браузеру, что это документ содержит html5 -->
<html lang=""> <!-- начало документа и язык содержимого -->
<head> 
    <meta charset="utf-8"> <!-- кодировка символов на странице(стандартная, поддерживает все необходимое) -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"><!-- это для сопоставления размеров мобильных устройств, корректной отрисовки -->
    <title>Моя страница</title><!-- заглавие страницы -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href=""><!-- ссылка на таблицу стилей-->
</head>

<body>
    <script src=""></script><!-- Вот тут либо ссылка, либо сам код. Уазывается в самом конце что бы не препятствовать отрисоке страницы браузером-->
</body>
</html>
```